# How to get a span from a div by span text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div where I have some span. Now I need to find a specific span based on its text. What can I try next? Here are my attempts below:

```
var spanExist = $('#activityDiv :span[text="hello"]').length;
alert("span exists   : " + spanExist);
```

but it gives the following error in console:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: span`

Comment: just change this to var spanExist = $('#activityDiv span[text="hello"]').length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```
var spanExist = $('#activityDiv span:contains("hello")').length;
alert("span exists   : " + spanExist);
```

---

If you want to get only elements with the exact match of text then use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) method.

```
var spanExist = $('#activityDiv span:contains("hello")').filter(function(){
   return $(this.text().trim() == "hello";
}).length;

alert("span exists   : " + spanExist);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var spanExist = $('#activityDiv span').text().trim();
if(spanExist == 'Hello'){
    alert("span exists   : " + spanExist);
}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='activityDiv'> 
  <span>Hello</span> <br/>
  
  
  
  </div>
```